# Adding 30 m SRTM DEM to Sentinel-2

Tags: raster, dem, sentinel-2

I have Sentinel-2 data (13 bands, spatial resolution 10m/20m/60m) and want to add 30 m SRTM DEM to increase accuracy while classification. The composite prepared should be kept at what spatial resolution?

Comment: Do you want to classify by elevation?

Comment: In a way, yes, elevation will be one of the various bands while classification.

Comment: Ok. I was surprised because is not a common task to include the elevation in a classification. In a sloped terrain seems to me that will be hard to find pixels of the same class.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what level of accuracy you want. If you want to preserve the original data, I would choose the highest resolution (10m).

Comment: Does this not violate the rule that one cannot go for fining the coarse resolution just by resampling?

Comment: In this case, there are multiple datasets, each with a different resolution. So, you won't get better resolution data for 30m dataset by going to 10m, but you preserve the original data of the 10m dataset it is used with.